# Session parameter number of concurrent users dependency for oracle DB

Tags: oracle, session, concurrency

IS the sessions parameter for ORACLE DB directly related to the number of concurrent users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you may have a for example a single user with 100 sessions. That parameter is related only to number of sessions. Wich user created the sessions does not have any importance.

However, the answer depends on what you mean by 'concurrent users'...